# Wand to create a drop shadow

Tags: imagemagick, python-3.9, wand, dropshadow

#### Background:

I have been trying to implement image enhancement using wand library to add drop shadow to a SingleImage.

I was able to create   drop-shadow using ImageMagick CLI, but want to replicate the same using wand package. As CLI solution reduced the throughput of the system while using python `subprocess` to execute ImageMagick commands, I am hopeful to improvise using wand package.

### Goal

Add drop shadow around an object using wand package. Successfully implemented using CLI commands.

Command:  `magick $in  \ \( +clone -background black -shadow "35x11+0+11" \)  -background none -compose DstOver -flatten -compose Over $out` x 7 with different shadow parameters.

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZs2J.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueKQ9.png)

ImageMagick Version: `7`

#### Attempts

Below code produced this image [wand package output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlig3.png)

python version : `3.9`
wand package version: `0.6.11`

```py
img = Image(filename="input.png", colorspace='rgb')
#pardon the indent 
    with img.clone() as shadow:
        shadow.background_color = Color('black')
        shadow.shadow(alpha=90, sigma=10, x=0, y=2)
        shadow.save(filename="shadow.png")


    with Image(filename="input.png", background=Color('none')) as front:
        with Image(filename="shadow.png") as back:
            with front.clone() as new_image:
                new_image.composite(back, 4, 4, operator='flatten')
                # merge layers has no effect
                # back.merge_layers('merge')
                new_image.save(filename="image_with_shadow.png")
```

One of the solution on internet was use to merge_layer, but I am unable to create the match CLI output. Can I add multiple shadows with different parameters on shadow image ?

Answer (score 0):

Standard shadow in Imagemagick command line is:

```
magick rose: \( +clone  -background navy  -shadow 80x3+5+5 \) +swap -background none -layers merge  +repage   shadow.png
```

So in your command it would be:

magick $in ( +clone -background black -shadow "35x11+0+11" )  +swap -background none -compose Over -layers merge +repage $out

Note the +swap, -compose over (only), -layers merge, and +repage

So swap your foreground and background images, use merge rather than flatten in the composite (though composite may not be correct as -layers merge is not the same as -composite).